# Akka message throttling

Tags: scala, concurrency, akka

I am trying to implement following scenario with Akka but hitting heap limitations (out of memory errors):

1. User uploads a text file(25mb aprox) containing around 1000000 lines.
2. After file gets uploaded HTTP 200 OK is sent back to the client and file processing is starting in the background.
3. Each line should be processed (saved to the database and external web service call should be made to look up the contents of the line with database update if lookup returned some results.)

Please suggest the approach/pattern.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: "hitting heap limitations" Where? Show us your code.

Comment: I'M guessing between "3." and "Please suggest..." is a question like "how do I throttle the actors so they don't take too many resources on the machine..."?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways for achieve this, for example:

1) Use [bounded mailbox](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/akka-user/3PB_T-OKyJU/napPKPbMhcsJ) for some of your actors, then your code that send messages to such actors will block if the target mailbox is full;

2) Use [work pulling model](http://www.michaelpollmeier.com/akka-work-pulling-pattern/) when some of your actors will "ask" for more work when idle.